# Installation of a .pkg file is nowhere to be seen

Tags: macos, install, pkg

I have gone through the install process of a .pkg file and when I look for it in `/Users/~/Library/Application Support` it's nowhere to be seen. I've only recently become a Mac user so it might be a newbie question but, how do I get to it?

MacBook Pro, OS X 10.7 Lion

Comment: Which .pkg exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The package contains some files to be installed somewhere in the file system, not necessarily in ~/Library/Application Support

A simple way to find out where files installed by the package will go in the file system is to use the [suspicious package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) QuickLook plugin. Note that install script in the package might still alter the filesystem in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X will only create this /Users/~/Library/Application Support/app directory when you open the application for the first time. Even then, not all apps require an Application Support directory as some are self contained.

What application are you attempting to run?

Comment: Subfolders under Application Support WILL NOT be created by the OS. They are created by the corresponding application.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Sorry. Mac OS X doesn't do the actual creating, but the fact remains that it will not be created until the app is opened for the first time...usually.

Comment: This is completely true.